# Debugging Appcelerator Windows Phone App with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, appcelerator, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to Debug my Windows Phone App which was developed with Appcelerator, I am unable to get it to work. Appcelerator has a option called Debug but nothing happens when I click on it. So is it a problem with my studio or is it not implemented yet in Appcelerator? What I am currently trying to do is to load the solution found in **phone.x86** into Visual Studio from Appcelerator's build directory. The solution is loading fine and the startup project is set to ALL_BUILD, but when I try to debug the solution in win32 mode it fails by giving this error :

> LNK1181   cannot open input file
>   'Native\Debug\TitaniumWindows_Native.lib' C:\Workspace\Appcelerator_Studio\SampleApp\build\windows\phone.x86\LINK

So I am assuming that this is not the correct was since the files generated are not for debugging environment. Any pointers on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging Titanium apps on Windows SDK has not been implemented yet:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7994

Our Q2 5.3 release will be fully focussed on Windows.